# How to retrieve value changes made from a For Loop within it's own method in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, random

I have a for loop within my main activity that is used to randomly shuffle/reassign the values within an array at the beginning of every time the application is opened.

I was told that for loops in Android Studio could only exist within a method (after getting errors when it was placed without one), but by doing so the random shuffling of the array is not carried over to the rest of the click events that are outside of the method and it just continues to output the same originally assigned values of in the array.

```
int[] money = {1,10,5,2,20,500,50,100,1000000,5000,1000,50000,100000,500000,250000,10000};

int swap1;
int swap2;
int temp;

Random random = new Random();
void what(){
    for (int j=0;j<16;j+=1)
    {
        swap1 = random.nextInt(16);
        swap2 = random.nextInt(16);
        temp = money[swap1];
        money[swap1] = money[swap2];
        money[swap2] = temp;
    }
}
```

The click events that are using the values from this array are like this one:

```
 one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View b) {

            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            counter++;
            money[0] = 0;

            Context one = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence message1 = "$1";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG; //this could also be a number
            final Toast one1 = Toast.makeText(one, message1, duration);
            one1.show();

            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                sum += money[x];
            }
            banker = sum / 16;

            Context oney = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence message1y = "The Banker offers you $" + banker + " for your case.";
            int durationy = Toast.LENGTH_LONG; //this could also be a number
            final Toast one1y = Toast.makeText(oney, message1y, durationy);
            one1y.show();

        }

    });
```

The aim was that if I were to click this button this time the money output was something like $500, and the next time I opened the application it would randomly shuffle and I might get a new value like $1.

Comment: where are you invoking `what();` ?

Comment: You mention "I was told that for loops in Android Studio could only exist within a method (after getting errors when it was placed without one)", I would just like to point out that this applies to all of Java, not just the program Android Studio. :)

Comment: On a side note, it is quite likely you don't actually need to get your Context from ApplicationContext because you wrote that code either inside an Activity class or a Fragment class. You could then use *this* if you are in an Activity or getActivity() if you are in a Fragment, because Activity extends a subclass of Context. You would then not need to explicitel declare a Context variable in your method (and you most certainly don't need 2, *one* and *oney* are pointing to the same object. Finally, are you sure you want to be showing 2 Toast like this ? They will be on top of each other...

Answer (score 3):

1. You might want to check out [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) instead of implementing it (don't reinvent the wheel etc).
2. Sounds like what you want to do is call the shuffle method from inside `onCreate()` and `onResume()`

Answer (score -1):

You should do the shuffle inside of the "onCreate" method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   ...
   int[] money = {1,10,5,2,20,500,50,100,1000000,5000,1000,50000,100000,500000,250000,10000};

int swap1;
int swap2;
int temp;

Random random = new Random();
void what(){
    for (int j=0;j<16;j+=1)
    {
        swap1 = random.nextInt(16);
        swap2 = random.nextInt(16);
        temp = money[swap1];
        money[swap1] = money[swap2];
        money[swap2] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A method inside a method ? Interesting concept, but I don't think this would even compile :) IMHO, it would work much better if the what() method is declared **outside** onCreate and you just call the method in onCreate. Then again, using Collections.shuffle() as suggested by alfasin is probably a better idea than implementing your own version of it. Unless of course you do it as an exercise ;)